# Blender can add verticies dynamically why can't Three.js?

Tags: three.js, buffer, blender

In Blender, or any multitude of modeling software you can add vertices on the fly.

However in Three.js this is would be an very expensive operation. You would have to replace the geometry with a new one every time.

What is the difference?

Comment: Blender is a modelling software that is designed to let you create 3D-objects and other stuff.
Three.js is a webgl-framework for creating games and other apps where you most of the time have static meshes. Not digital content creation software in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Blender ultimately does the same thing. When adding geometry (vertex, faces, edges, etc) you effectively have to re-upload a  buffer containing the vertices / faces / texture UV coordinates to the GPU when they are changed. This is why it seems complex. You can easily wrap these concepts in functions to make it easier on yourself.